# "Export and reimport" xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, import, export, project

I have an app that is working fine, called A, and i've been asked to create a light version of this app (called B). Now what i did is copy paste the whole A project and started tweaking/reducing it, and then saving it as is. So i have two A projects, with (i'm guessing) same ID's and same pretty much everything related to the Apple Developer side of things (profiles and such).

Now I obviously need to do what I didn't plan : Edit those things.

I can edit the bundle name, scheme name, project name, icon name, and so on, but i'm pretty sure i can't edit the app ID, and therefore will only have problems when dealing with provisioning profiles.

My questions are :

1. Am I wrong? do I simply need to create a prov profile & new app ID in the app dev center ? (i'll try that while i'm waiting for an answer anyways)

*EDIT : I can't seem to make it work " no matching prov profile found ", " don't match ", i've ahd many different errors that i couldn't fix :l*

2. If i'm right and have to create a new project and "import" everything in, knowing i then have ot deal with provisioning profiles & app ID, what is the best way to do it? Without breaking any symbolic link or anything important that i don't know about. C

Thanks

Note : I have about 300 files in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to copy-paste your project and split it in 2 ways. But a better solution would be `git`, making a new branch.

Bundle id can be changed by renaming the project name. And yes, you should do a new provisioning profile for this app. You can do a provisioning profile like `com.example.*` and use it with all your apps. I don't know if it's recommended though.

All the settings can be changed in the `<ProjectName>-Info.plist` file.

You don't need any *Import & Export*.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, after fighting with the certificates, private key pairs, profiles, code signing and finally archiving, i got it working.